# Adding a key with an empty value to Guava Multimap

Tags: guava, multimap

I have a need to add a key to a Guava Multimap with an empty collection as the value.  How do I accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
map.put( "my key", null );
```

but calling get() returns a list with one element, which is null.  I worked around this by doing the following:

```
map.putAll("my key2", new ArrayList())
```

but I'm wondering if this is a bad thing to do?  I know Guava automatically removes a key when the last value is removed to keep containsKey() consistent.  What's my best option here?

Comment: How about you tell us *why* you feel you need to make a Multimap behave in a way it wasn't intended?

Comment: It's just the nature of the data.  I have a set of keys, some of which have values associated with them, and a few who don't. (The actual keys/values come from a DB).  If this is a bad use case for Multimap, that's fine, I'm open to other solutions.  The original impl in this code used a Map<String, List<String>> and switching to Multimap seemed natural.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Multimap` *deliberately* forbids this approach, and your proposed workaround is a no-op -- it won't actually do anything.

The way `Multimap` works is that `multimap.get(key)` never returns null, but always returns some collection -- possibly empty.  (But the backing `Multimap` implementation probably doesn't actually store anything for that key, and if a key isn't mapped to a *nonempty* collection, it won't e.g. appear in the `keySet()`.  [`Multimap` is *not* a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap-is-not-a-map).)

If you want to map to an empty collection, you must use `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Answer (score 8):

As the [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) covers, a multimap is conceptually a bunch of key-value pairs where the keys are not necessarily unique, for example a=1, a=2, b=3. If there are no values associated with a, then there are no key-value pairs for a, so a does not exist in the multimap.

One thing you can do is keep a separate `Set<K>` for the entire universe of keys you care about, or just to keep the additional keys that correspond to no values. Another is to use a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, or a `Map<K, Something>` where `Something` contains a collection that might or might not be empty.