# TreeMultimap doesn't allow null or empty values?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I want duplicate values + natural order + empty, which collection support these features?

I have tried Multihashmap and TreeMultimap. Treemultimap didn't allow empty values, even I have key, but its allowing...

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    TreeMultimap<String, String> mp = TreeMultimap.create();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    mp.put("a", "10"); 
    mp.put("a", "11"); 
    mp.put("a", "12"); 
    mp.put("b", "13"); 
    mp.put("c", "14"); 
    mp.put("e", "");
    mp.put("b", "1");
    mp.put("b", "2");
    mp.put("b", "3");
    List list = null; 
    for(String key : mp.keySet())  
    {
        System.out.println("mp.values()"+mp.values());
        int itemcount = mp.size();
        System.out.println(itemcount);

    }
```

expected output format as

```
a 10 11 12 
a 10 11 12
a 10 11 12
b 13 1 2 3
b 13 1 2 3
b 13 1 2 3
b 13 1 2 3
c 14
e
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:oracle] and [tag:sql]? If there's some relation to these tags, please mention it in the text. Otherwise they don't apply.

Comment: I'm just wondering , last 3 hours i didn't get any feedback.But normally responses are very fast in stackoverflow.

Comment: So that's why you add unrelated tags to get some more input? That's an abuse of the system. Instead, try to update your question with additional findings or details (for example, what's the *actual* output of your code?)

Comment: Yes, front layer looks very hard to achive this scenrio.Thats reason i would have added sql, to get resultset sa above format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a key with an empty value to Guava Multimap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587895/adding-a-key-with-an-empty-value-to-guava-multimap)

Answer (score 2):

That's very deliberately how `Multimap` works.  Putting an empty `String` and a normal `String` into a `Multimap` makes exactly no difference, and a `Multimap` will treat a key without any values as completely nonexistent.  Please read [`Multimap` Is Not A `Map`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap_Is_Not_A_Map) from the Guava wiki.

Comment: Actaully item count is 9 but above output is 8 . Its elminate the empty values row.

Comment: mp.values()[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 14, ]
8

Comment: but i need values if empty also

Comment: What?  The number of elements in `[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 14, ]` is 8.  That's the correct answer, and it includes the empty value.  It's not clear what you want instead.

Comment: No , I want empty value too..because key total count is 9 but value total is 8 . Look at the programe , there is one key e, total count not included the e element.As we calculated size for mp object.It should return 9.

Comment: When I run your program, I get out 9.  Are you running the exact same program as you gave in the original question?

Comment: Do you have any idea about to get the values as like mentioned in the question ?

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by "to get the values as like mentioned in the question."  Please be more specific what you want and don't have.