# How to check value of Multimap is null or empty?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I am using Multimap from Guava as shown below since I can have same keys many times but with different values.

```
Multimap<Long, Plesk> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
// populate data into map

// extract value from the above map
Collection<Plesk> plesk = map.get(id);
```

And now from the same multimap I am extracting a particular key value. Now how can I check whether `plesk` variable is null or not? After I print out my `map` variable, I see one entry as:

```
1100178=[null]
```

so `plesk` variable is getting value as `[null]` for id `1100178` and if I use below code to check for null and empty then it doesn't work:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(plesk)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

What is the right way to check whether value of multimap is null or not?

Comment: Did you try `if (plesk  != null && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(plesk)) {
    // do stuff
} else { //null or empty, do other stuff }` ?

Comment: isEmpty already check for null.

Comment: But it's not null, it's a collection containing one null element. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a key with an empty value to Guava Multimap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587895/adding-a-key-with-an-empty-value-to-guava-multimap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `Multimap.get(key)` is never `null`. If there are no values associated with that key, it returns an empty `Collection`.

Your `plesk` collection appears to be a collection with a single element, and that single element is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, the result of `multimap.get(key)` is never null and returns an empty collection if there are no values associated.
From your question, I can understand that you want to check whether there is a value present or not and perform some action if there is no value found for a specific key.
I would do something like this:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("Name", "SomeName");
multimap.put("ID", "");
multimap.put("City", "SomeCity");
Collection<String> contentsofID = multimap.get("ID");
if (contentsofID.toString().equals("[]")) {
    // This means that there is no value in it
    // Then perform what you want
}
```